# Including Wicket HTML files in jar file wtih a SBT build

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, wicket

I am trying to convert MVN project into SBT. All the compilation and packaging are OK. But I have one problem.
Here I have wicket html pages and I want to include them in the output jar file, (in the same path they exists in src directory).

with maven, we can very easily do this with

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

How can I do the same with SBT in the simplest way...??

**NOTE: Google show me some sophisticated ways to do with some plugins, defining new tasks etc...
But I believe there should be a simple stupid way to do this,**

This is the simplest way I found so far:
The following solution can be used to map a single file, but I wanted to do the same for a directory

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) += {
  (baseDirectory.value / "src"/ "main"/ "java" / "com" / "csl" / "as" / "web" / "pages" / "BasePage.html") -> "com/csl/as/web/pages/BasePage.html"
}
```

Comment: You could maybe get some hints here https://github.com/pussinboots/wicket-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this, it is just same as we did with maven. Just specify an additional resource directory.

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "src"/ "main"/ "java"
```

This will copy the whole thing in 'src/main/java' into the root of jar file. Finally I have my *.html* files with *.class* files.

And you may use *excludeFilter* to get only the required files into jar.